# User Authentication with stored hashes - Crypt and Blowfish

Tags: php, authentication, blowfish

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm hoping someone could help me understand blowfish and crypt. I got through to inserting an encrypted password into the database but I'm having trouble with user authentication. I've been looking at different posts on SO as well as blogs/tutorials and it doesn't seem any of them are authenticating stored passwords. I've found [this blog](http://www.sitepoint.com/password-hashing-in-php/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548248/bycript-blowfish-and-salts-with-existing-auth-system) semi helpful but can't figure out authentication once the password is stored.
At registration, the user's password input is encrypted using this function then stored in a `users` table:

```
function crypt_pass($pass){
    if(defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH){
        $salt = '$2y$11$'.substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 22);
        return crypt($pass, $salt);
    }
}
```

then at login this is the function:

```
function user_authenticate($username, $password_input){
    include '../connection/dbconnect.php';
    $errors = "";
    if ($user_exists->num_rows < 1 || $user_exists->num_rows > 1){
       //other checks - username, activated status, etc.
    } else{
        $user_match = $connect->query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '$username' LIMIT 1");
        $user_id = $user_match->fetch_assoc();
        $get_pw = $connect->query("SELECT `pass_w` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '$username'");
        $pw_match = $get_pw->fetch_assoc();
        if ($user_match->num_rows != 1 || crypt($password_input, $pw_match['pass_w']) != $pw_match['pass_w']){
            $errors = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';
            return $errors;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Typing in the right password gives me "That username/password combination is incorrect". I believe I'm using `crypt()` as instructed in the posts I've read. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using IRCMaxell's Password Compat library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat  this will give you password_hash() and password_verify() methods, which use BLOWFISH algo, and are implemented as standard in php5.5